# Flutter Textformfield How to center text in a Textformfield

Tags: flutter, textformfield

how it is possible to center the Text in a Textformfield?

[image]

Here we see two Textformfield with value 800 and 80. Now I want to center the content so that the 80 is centered under the 800, like in the second picture showed.

[image]

I think its just a minor thing.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use   `textAlign: TextAlign.center,`

[image: output]

```
 SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```